# how to change background color of a customized bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return Scaffold(
      //  key: scaffoldKey,
extendBody: true,
       // bottomNavigationBar:
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: 80,
          child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(80.0),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
          //  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
           // onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: 'Search',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
          ),
              ),
        ),
     
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 7, 135),
```

[image]I want to change the color of bottom navigation bar from green into transparent...I already gave white but showing like this(given photo)..how to do this?[image]
(that green color is background color of my scaffold)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i updated the code and image..i want to remove that pink color thats my scaffold background color,i want to transparent

Answer (score 0):

add color to your Container like this
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
color:Colors.red,
height: 80,
child: ClipRRect(...)
)

Comment: no way ..still showing pink color(thats my scaffold bg color)

Comment: that work for me
can you send your code with Container color

Comment: i mean its not working with transparent(when i change pink to transparent its still showing pink)..could you run with transparent color?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. It seems like OK for me. Your code is working on my code.

[Bottom Nav Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEi9c.png)

And here is my full code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 7, 135),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const HomeAppBarWidget(),
              const SizedBox(height: kPadding24),
              const SearchAndFilterWidget(),
              const SizedBox(height: kPadding24),
              HomeCategoriesWidget(
                current: _current,
                onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _current = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: kPadding24),
              const NearForYouWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 80,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            //  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
            // onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: 'Search',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```